# Issues with IF AND statement in Excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, percentile

I'm having issues with a "PERCENTILE(IF(AND(" statement. I want to return a percentile based on two criteria, but for some reason it keeps giving me "$0." What am I doing wrong that is causing this to return nothing?

```
=PERCENTILE(IF(AND($E:$E=$J$26,$A:$A = $K28), $H:$H), 0.33333)
```

I expect to get the Percentile of the total $ value (H column) of customers organized by two criteria: 1) same Industry (E column and J26) and 2) same Area (A column and K28). This information is being pulled from a pivot table.

Comment: For older versions of Excel you to entry it as array formula by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. This will wrap the formula with curly bracket automatically. It will look like `{=PERCENTILE(IF(AND($E:$E=$J$26,$A:$A = $K28), $H:$H), 0.33333)}`.

Comment: May be you can use `AGGREGATE()` with the `function_num` as `16` for `PERCENTILE.INC` or `18` for `PERCENTILE.EXC` so that said it could be like this. `=AGGREGATE(16,6,$H:$H/(($E:$E=$J$26)*($A:$A=$K28)),0.33333)` also don't pass entire columns, try to make it absolute.

Comment: Don't you need $K$28 in the second equation?